# The Hermitian condition is equivalent to $\nabla_{JX}J=J(\nabla_XJ)$, right?

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry

I saw the property $\nabla_{JX}J=J(\nabla_XJ)$ on a Hermitian manifold in a paper, where $X$ is a vector field, $J$ is complex structure and $\nabla $ is the Levi-Civita connection. This seems to be a well-known conclusion, but I can't find its proof. By a simple calculation, I obtain the following result
$$
(\nabla_{JX}J)Y-J(\nabla_XJ)Y=-N_J(X,Y)+(\nabla_{JY}J)X-J(\nabla_YJ)X,\quad \forall X,Y\in \Gamma(TM),
$$
where $N_J(X,Y)=[X,Y]+J[JX,Y]+J[X,JY]-[JX,JY]$ is the Nijenhuis tensor. That is, if set $A(X,Y)=(\nabla_{JX}J)Y-J(\nabla_XJ)Y$, then we have
$$
A(X,Y)=-N_J(X,Y)+A(Y,X).
$$
I don't know how to discuss it.

Cite: The 14th line of page 2591 of the paper [Fu-Zhou](https://doi.org/10.1007/s11425-021-1943-8)

[image]

Comment: Which paper are you referring to?

Comment: The 14th line of page 2591 of the paper    https://doi.org/10.1007/s11425-021-1943-8

Comment: I've figured out how to prove it. Thank you!@MichaelAlbanese

Comment: That's great! You should write the proof as an answer.

Comment: Okay, I have added an answer. Thank you for your attention  to this problem.@MichaelAlbanese

Answer (score 1):

In fact, by simple calculations, we have
$$
A(Y,X)-A(X,Y)=N_J(X,Y)
$$
and
$$
\begin{split}
-2\langle A(X,Y),JZ\rangle =&\langle N_J(X,Y),JZ\rangle \\&-\langle N_J(X,Z),JY\rangle -\langle N_J(Y,Z),JX\rangle 
\end{split}
$$
for any $X,Y,Z\in \Gamma(TM)$. Hence the conclusion that $\nabla_{JX}J=J(\nabla_XJ)$ is equivalent to $N_J=0$ follows from the above two equalities.

Comment: Are you sure its $2\langle A(Y, X), JZ\rangle$ and not $-2\langle A(X, Y), JZ\rangle$? The latter is what appears in equation $(21)$ of Gauduchon's *Complex Structures on Compact Conformal Manifolds of Negative Type*.

Comment: Yes, I have a typo here. It should be $\langle -A(X,Y),JZ\rangle $. Also, is there a downloadable link to Gaidochon's Complex Structures on Compact Conformal Manifolds of Negative Type? Thank you!@MichaelAlbanese

Comment: Oh, I just found a preview version of Google Books.@MichaelAlbanese

Comment: Also see equation $(2.2.8)$ of Gauduchon's *Hermitian Connections and Dirac Operators* which can be found [here](http://verbit.ru/MATH/Gauduchon_Hermitian_Operators01.pdf).

Comment: Thanks!@MichaelAlbanese